# I can write on a unplugged removeable storage path

Tags: android, linux, android-file, android-storage

I have an industrial Android board "Allwinner" intented for a kiosk system that mounts removeable drives like that:

```
/storage/card    -- SD-card
/storage/udisk3  -- USB storage device via USB-OTG
```

Everything works as expected. I get (un)mounted notifications and can read and write on the storage. I even don't have to ask the user for permission to use the removeable storage although it's Android 6 which is great for a kiosk system!

However, I can sometimes manage to write on the `/storage/usdisk3` path **when no removable is plugged in!** The files then are stored on the internal storage and appear instead of the content of the removeable storage. Once a removeable storage is connected again, I see its content under that path until it's unplugged.

Unfortunatly, I found out about that behavior long after I implemented the features that make use of `/storage/usdisk3` ;(

So, I have to work around that anomalie and differentiate if the content of `/storage/usdisk3` really is a removeable storage.

Questions

- Did you also manage to write on the destination of an unplugged removeable storage device?
- What is a safe way to find out whether or not the content of `/storage/usdisk3` really belongs to a removeable storage?